# Apply css rule only text in a selector not span

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to add style only to text inner i a selector, ignoring span selector in same tag.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evn789yh/4/)

```css
body {
  color: yellow;
}

ul a:not(span) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com"><span>this is</span> google page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Declare span{color:blue} or body span{color:blue}

Comment: This works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css cascades, therefore the span will always inherit the colour of the anchor unless you tell it otherwise (below I reset the span style to it's initial colour)

```css
body {
  color: yellow;
}

ul a {
  color: red;
}

ul a>span {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com"><span>this is</span> google page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately, if you want the span yellow, then you have to manually set that as there is nothing to tell the span to skip a level of inheritance:

```
ul a>span {
  color: yellow;
}
```